# Styling $(this).text in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is that a way to style my text inside the JQuery, for this example:

Eg. When I clicked on the button 'Show Table' will turn red to blue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hide').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#category-table').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).text("Show Table"); /*style this text color: red;*/
            $('#category-table').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).text("Hide Table"); /*style this text color: blue;*/
            $('#category-table').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.css()` function to specify the style of the element:

```
$(this).text("Show Table").css('color', 'red');
```

Or you could have CSS classes, e.g.

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

and add the class:

```
$(this).text("Show Table").removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Sorry I am quite new in this area.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I got another question. How if i want to style text 'Show' from red to blue. But text 'Table' from maybe blue to red in the same time. So it will be something like eg: '<red>Show</red> <blue>Table'</blue> to '<blue>Show</blue> <red>Table</red>'

Comment: You need to split it up into separate `<span>` elements so you can give them different styles.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

e.g. `$(this).text("Show Table").css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using jQuery.

```
$(this).css('color', '#ff0000'); /*style this text color: red;*/
$(this).text("Show Table");
```

---

```
$(this).css('color', '#0000ff'); /*style this text color: blue;*/
$(this).text("Hide Table");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hide').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#category-table').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).text("Show Table"); /*style this text color: red;*/

        $(this).css("color","red"); // if you want set color (you can set color as 'red' or '#ff0000')
        $(this).addClass("myRedClass"); //this is better, you can set class and change him in styles

        $('#category-table').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).text("Hide Table"); /*style this text color: blue;*/
        /* copy from red  */
        $('#category-table').show();
    }
  });
});
```